aria-label content is not being read by iOS VoiceOver on iOS 17.7 for a disabled button
The below element is a disabled button on a web page. When using screen readers on Android and JAWS on desktop, the element is announced as "Button Text Disabled button". On iOS using VoiceOver, this implementation does not work, and it only announces the visual text, "Button Text". From what I understand, iOS VoiceOver should announce the aria-label, but it does not.
export const example = () => {
  return (
    <div
      tabIndex={0}
      style={{
        opacity: "40%",
        color: "#3057B9",
        display: "inline"
      }}
      data-testid="example"
      aria-label="This content should be announced"
    >
      Button Text{" "}
      <span className="visually-hidden">Disabled button</span>
    </div>
  );
};

I added the aria-label to try to get iOS VoiceOver to read the aria-label, but it ignores it and only reads the Button Text.

Could you post the actual HTML code generated ?  Thank you.

This is an element that we render by simply calling  in the code

I mean the real code generated and finally displayed/rendered to the end user. In any case I have maybe an idea: try to add role="button". If it works then I will explain in a real answer.
